# Sharepoint 2013 - Javascript Code for File Upload - Max limit exceeded ?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, file-upload

I have an issue with uploading file > 2MB.
I have used javascript code to upload files from my UI. 
In Central Admin, the allowed file size has been increased to 10MB.

Whenever I try to upload a file > 2MB, its not allowing me.

Throws the following error:

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

"The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes."

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of places that you need to change this on, You have done central admin but you also need to do web application web.config:

search for `httpRuntime` and update to this:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="5120" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

above allows only 5mb max, to increase the number:

function:

```
mb * 1024 = total bytes;
```

example i want to increase it to 28 MB than i would do: 28 * 1024 = 28672

Answer (score 1):

Th following approaches are commonly used when uploading files via SharePoint CSOM/JSOM

### FileCollection.Add method

[FileCollection.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecollection.add(v=office.15).aspx) adds a file to the collection based on provided file creation information.

CSOM Example:

```
public static void UploadFile(string filePath,ClientContext context, string listTitle)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation
    {
                Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath),
                Url = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    };

    var targetList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var uploadFile = targetList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
    context.Load(uploadFile);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The above code might fail throwing a `(400) Bad Request error` depending on the file size.

The following code is used to set a higher received message size for the WCF service of the client object model (client.svc) using [SPClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spclientrequestservicesettings.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=office.14).aspx):

```
public static void SetMaxMessageSize(int sizeMb)
{
     var ws = SPWebService.ContentService;
     var clientSettings = ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings;
     clientSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = sizeMb*1024* 1024; 
     ws.Update();
 }
```

> Note: This is not the same as the max. file size upload limit option
>   available in the web application settings.

### File.SaveBinaryDirect method

[File.SaveBinaryDirect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect(v=office.15).aspx) uploads the specified file to a SharePoint site without requiring an ExecuteQuery() method call.

This methods *uses HTTP DAV and sends raw binary across the wire and does not increase the message size*.  It is also the **preferred** upload method when using managed client object model.

CSOM example:

```
private static void UploadFile(string filePath,ClientContext context, string listTitle)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        context.Load(list.RootFolder);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fileName);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
     }
 }
```

Comment: The above is not javascript code as the original poster was asking.

Answer (score 1):

I already posted this on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861407/sharepoint-error-the-server-does-not-allow-messages-larger-than-2097152-bytes/24692287#24692287), so here goes...

SharePoint has its own limits for CSOM. Unfortunately, these limits cannot be configured in Central Administration and also cannot be set using CSOM for obvious reasons.

When googling for the issue, mostly a solution is given by setting the `ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize` property to the desired size.

Call the following PowerShell script from SharePoint Management Shell :

```
$ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 
$ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 209715200 
$ws.Update()
```

This will set the limit to 200 MB.

However, **in SharePoint 2013 Microsoft apparently added another configuration setting** to also limit the amount of data which the server shall process from a CSOM request (Why anyone would configure this one differently is beyond me...). After reading a very, very long SharePoint Log file and crawling through some disassembled SharePoint server code, I found that this parameter can be set via the property `ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxParseMessageSize`.

We are now using the following script with SharePoint 2013 and it works great:

```
$ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 
$ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 209715200 
$ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxParseMessageSize = 209715200 
$ws.Update()
```

Hope that saves some people a headache!